# O-Auth 2.0 - Server-side Login

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I am developing a web-service and I would like my users to log-in using some known authentication provider (facebook,google,etc..) instead of registering a new user.

I will take Stack overflow as an example for such service.

From what I understood from reading O-Auth tutorials the flow should go like this:

```
1. A user log in for the first time to Stack Overflow
2. User is asked to log in via Google or Facebook.
3. Stack overflow redirects the user to Google along with Stack Overflow app ID and a Redirect URL (Callback)
4. Google ask the user: "Stack overflow wants to access your account" - allow/deny. 
5. Assuming the user allowed, Google will redirect the user back to Stack Overflow, and will send a Token back to stack overflow servers (the Callback URL) as well as a client ID (unique google id)
6. If this client id does not exists, Stack overflow creates a new user in its database with this client id, if it does exists, it will just return the user's data (e.g. questions asked)
7. Using the saved TOKEN, stack overflow servers can grab information from Google (if needed) without the user interaction (since the user allowed access to Google)
```

Is this flow is accurate? If so, here's the main question.

**Client Side**

The client now wants to send/receive information to/from Stack Overflow (e.g. post a question).

- What kind of information does the **client** need to send to Stack overflow servers In order for them to confirm that this is indeed the user?

**Server Side**

- How does Stack overflow, Validates this user?  (i.e. what kind of information does Stack overflow save on the user to identify him? Google/Facebook ID?)
- Stack overflow servers wants to grab information from the User's Google account (the user allowed this operation), what kind of information does stackover flow servers need to send Google in order to retrieve this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thunk your assumptions are mostly accurate. There is one exception though:

> 5) Assuming the user allowed, Google will redirect the user back to Stack Overflow, and will send a Token back to stack overflow servers (the Callback URL) as well as a client ID (unique google id)

Normally an OAuth2 server does NOT return a clientId or any user details, it returns ONLY the token. Actually, the oauth client (i.e. stackoverflow in your example) should not be aware of the user identity at all. OAuth2 is designed to enable accessing a restricted resource for clients without gaining user identity.

However, if the client (stackoverflow) asks for access to the user account (as in your example), it CAN query some user details afterwards, using the token. User details (e.g. identifier) is completely up to the authorization server (i.e. Google). Even if the server provides such internal details in query results, you (stackoverflow) still should generate a clientId based on generally available, provider-agnostic information only, e.g. use the email address.

This should have answered your two server-side questions, too.

> What kind of information does the client need to send to Stack overflow servers In order for them to confirm that this is indeed the user?

For the remaining part of the scenario, roles should be completely reversed. Google gets out of the scope, Stackoverflow will be the OAuth2 SERVER, and your application will be the CLIENT. If your application wants to post or read questions, it should require authorization from the stackoverflow user to do so. If authorization is granted, a token is returned, you application should use the token to access the questions on Stackoverflow. So the answer is: NOTHING, only the token.

To correctly finish the answer, I have to confess I'm not closely familiar with implementation details of the mentioned sites (google. facebook, stackoverflow, etc). But if they comply to the OAuth2 standard, they should behave as I have described. Familiar users, please let me know if the scenario is implemented differently for any site!